# The identifier cannot be an empty string

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq To Sql to save an entity that has many child entities in it, and was just wondering if anyone ever got this error: `The identifier cannot be an empty string`

I was just wondering if anyone has run into to it and what did you do to fix the issue?  Maybe I'll get lucky and one of your solutions will work.

This probably won't help much but here is where the code is failing

```
public void SaveJob(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

   Job = JobEditorUtilities.CreateNewJob(jobid, SettingsManager.OpsMgrSettings.Region.Trim(), _db);
    try
    {
        var canSaveJob = CanSaveJob();
        if (canSaveJob)
        {
            JobEditorUtilities.PrepareJobForSaving(Job);
            if (newjob)
                _db.JobNumbers.InsertOnSubmit(Job);

            var a = _db.GetChangeSet();
            _db.SubmitChanges();   // fails here
            RenameJobNumberIfNecessary();

        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}


    public static JobNumber CreateNewJob(int jobid, string region, DataAccessDataContext dc)
    {
        var job = new JobNumber();
        job.JobID = jobid;

        InitializeSubContractor(dc, job);
        job.GWDRunSummaryDatas = new GWDRunSummaryData();
        job.CorrectionsApplieds = new CorrectionsApplied();
        job.MonitorInfos = new MonitorInfo();
        InitializeGWDHeader(dc, job);
        job.Rpt_Details = new Rpt_Detail();
        job.RunningModes = new RunningMode();
        job.SafetyIssuesTotals = new SafetyIssuesTotals();
        job.SafetyIssueTotals = new SafetyIssueTotals();
        switch (region)
        {
            case "NA":
                InitializeNA_Header(dc, job);
                job.NA_WRdetails = new NA_WRdetail();
                InitializeNA_BillingCompany(dc, job);
                job.NA_RigDetails = new NA_RigDetail();
                job.NA_Holedetails = new NA_Holedetail();
                job.NA_Salesmans = new NA_Salesman();
                InitializeNA_WL_Company(dc, job);
                break;
            case "EU":
                InitializeEAC_Header(dc, job);
                break;
        }



        return job;
    }
   private static void InitializeNA_WL_Company(DataAccessDataContext dc, JobNumber job)
    {
        job.NA_WL_Companies = new NA_WL_Company();
        job.NA_WL_Companies.Resource =
            dc.Resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Refno == job.NA_WL_Companies.WL_companyid);
    }

    private static void InitializeGWDHeader(DataAccessDataContext dc, JobNumber job)
    {
        job.GWD_Header2s = new GWD_Header2();
        job.GWD_Header2s.GWDDirComp2 =
            dc.GWDDirComp2s.FirstOrDefault(g => g.ID == job.GWD_Header2s.MWD_Company);

    }


    private static void InitializeNA_BillingCompany(DataAccessDataContext dc, JobNumber job)
    {
        job.NA_BillingCompanies = new NA_BillingCompany();
        job.NA_BillingCompanies.Resource =
            dc.Resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Refno == job.NA_BillingCompanies.Billingcompanyid);
    }
    private static void InitializeSubContractor(DataAccessDataContext dc, JobNumber job)
    {
        job.Subcontractors = new Subcontractor();
        job.Subcontractors.Resource =
            dc.Resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Refno == job.Subcontractors.SubcontractorID);
    }

    private static void InitializeNA_Header(DataAccessDataContext dc, JobNumber job)
    {
        job.NA_Headers = new NA_Header();
        job.NA_Headers.RigType1 = dc.RigTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == job.NA_Headers.RigType);
        job.NA_Headers.Well_Locn1 = dc.Well_Locns.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ID == job.NA_Headers.Well_Locn);
    }

    private static void InitializeEAC_Header(DataAccessDataContext dc, JobNumber job)
    {
        job.EAC_Headers = new EAC_Header();

    }
```

Comment: this is a query processing error. Try and put a breakpoint right before your Linq quer(y)(ies) to find out which one is giving you trouble. Then post that part of code if you will (in an edit of your question).

Comment: you can always determine which SQL statement is produced by LinqToSQL using the SQL Server Profiler and then trace it in SQL Management studio.  Obviously, some wrong value is passed to the SQL query, but I doubt that it is possible to answer what is wrong without the code.

Comment: where does `Job` come from?

Comment: Are you developing on SQL Server CE? If so, this is one of the errors on [this list on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172350.aspx). Note the part in the yellow box: "If you experience any errors that have the prefix 'Internal error' when you use SQL Server Compact, try the operation again as the error might not reproduce. If the error appears again, you should immediately contact Microsoft Product Support Services. The internal errors cannot be resolved by common troubleshooting techniques."

Comment: @Paolo I am using SQL Server CE

Comment: I am starting over. I decided to change the way I initialize the children. In the above code, I was trying to initialize them all at once.  I am now going to try to just initialize them as needed and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting over and just initializing the child entities as needed, instead of initializing them all at once.  That seemed to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by one of your class field mappings having a blank 'Source' property. If you are using the LINQ to SQL designer, click on every field of every class, and make sure the 'Source' property is not blank. If you are creating the class manually, make sure that you have no ColumnAttributes with a blank string in the 'Name' field.